# Probability of seeing a patient

Tags: probability

Question:

> A physical therapist has 20 patients. The therapist sees 5 of them
>   once a week, 9 of them twice a week, and the other patients three
>   times a week. If one of the physical therapist's patient is selected
>   at random, what is the probability that this patient is seen for
>   therapy fewer than three times a week?

My solution/reasoning:

> Since there are 5 patients who come each week, total visits = 5. For 9
>   patients who come twice, total visits = 18 and for the rest, 6
>   patients thrice a week, total visits = 18.
>
> Now, if I go and see who the patient is, then the probability of
>   seeing the patient who visits either once or twice a week = `(total
>   no. of visits of both the patients) / (total no. of visits of all the
>   patients)`. My answer = `(5 + 18) / (5 + 18 + 18)` = `0.56`.

However, the answer at the back is given `0.70` which is what you get when you divide 14 (no. of patients making fewer than 3 visits) / 20 (total no. of patients).

What is wrong with my reasoning in for this particular question?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct if one picks an *appointment* at random, and asks the patient for that appointment how many times they are seen per week.  But here, one is picking a *patient* at random.

Comment: @BrianTung All right, got it. Also, I think that this should be an answer and if you post yours, I will accept yours instead of wece's for you answered the question first.

Comment: I appreciate your consideration, but I think it's better not to duplicate a correct answer, even at the loss of those precious points! :-)  But thanks very kindly.

Comment: @BrianTung As you wish. :)

Comment: @BrianTung If it's true that your comment came first I don't mind deleting my answer to let you get the point :) I'm not that active on the site, hence I don't absolutely need 15 points ... What I have is plenty enough to start a bounty if need, that all I'm looking for. Cheers

Comment: Thanks very much, but please don't do that. We posted at essentially the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your solution you pick a visit a random during a week, and wonder if the patient comes fewer than three times a week. But the question is to pick a patient at random.

So your states space is the patients (20) and the positive cases are the 14 patients that come less then 3 times a week, hence the result 0.7.

I hope it clarifies it for you.